# User address sub fields not showing in userinfo response

Tags: keycloak

I have added a mapper to my client with a mapper type of 'User Address' and enabled the 'Add to userinfo' option
[image]

I have then set an address attribute on my user as follows:

[image]

When making a request to the userinfo endpoint I just get back an empty address object:

[image]

Have I missed out something here? We are using keycloak 3.2.1 also.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your user's attributes must be passed as single key/value pairs , not as full JSON object. 
[image]

And the values in the mapper must be filled in as well : [image]

Comment: Ok, I have tried this but still only getting an empty address object back. I also tried with a new token just to be sure. I must be doing something stupid here, missed out a step perhaps. Does the way I have added the address mapper look correct to you?

Comment: Ah no missed that, you need to specify the names in your mapper , let me update the answer. It should be already filled in when you choose a "built-in" mapper.

Comment: Thanks that worked! When I hovered over the question mark symbols on the user attribute field labels in the mapper, I assumed the defaults they referred to were already set and that you didnt have to set them in the fields here.

Comment: I agree the tooltip text is a bit confusing, I will report that to the team.